# git rebase squash commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I have my own `dev` branch checkout from `master`, and there is another `dev2` branch owned by another guy and still in **DEVELOPING**.
I need use the changes on `dev2`, so I use `git merge dev2` on my `dev` branch.

On next day, the guy developing on `dev2` wrote some new codes and used "`git rebase`-liked" cmd to SQUASH his commits into a new one, and then `push -f` to `origin` , so I used `git merge dev2` again to get the latest change, however, the conflict occurs.

I don't even make ANY changes on my `dev` yet, but it's just conflicted. It is easy to image if I made my own changes, there must be more conflicts.

Does there is some **BEST PRACTICE** to avoid conflicts in such situation?

Comment: The best practice is for the owner of the `dev2` branch to avoid playing such games as rebasing and force pushing, as it will cause problems for everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't allow people to force push. It should be exceptional.
2. If you always need the work that is on another branch, you probably want to work directly on this branch
3. A guy that is "still developing" don't push until work is done and commits are properly squashed/commented/etc

Answer (score 1):

## Usually we have 2 method to collobrate.

Both git rebase and git merge are used to obtain from a branch and merge to the current branch, but they adopt different working methods. The following work scenario illustrates the difference.

Scenes:
[image: 2 seperated branch]

As shown in the figure: you are developing new features in a feature branch, and at the same time, there are new commits in the master branch.

In order to merge new commits on master to your feature branch, you have two options: mrege or rebase

### git merge

Execute the following commands:

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

Or perform simpler:

```
git merge master feature
```

Then git will automatically generate a new commit (merge commit)
look like this on the feature at this time:

[image: git merge]

- Marge Features: Automatically create a new commit.
  If you encounter a conflict during the merge, you only need to modify and re-commit.
- Advantages: Record the real commit status, including the details of each branch.
- Disadvantages: Because each merge will automatically generate a merge commit , So when using some git GUI tools, especially when commits are frequent, I see that the branches are very messy.

### git rebase

The essence is rebasing.
rebasing is the find common ancestor.

Execute the following commands:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

look like this:

[image: git rebase]

- Rebase features: will merge the previous commit history.
- Advantages: get a more concise project history, remove merge commit
- Disadvantages: if there is a code problem in the merge , it is not easy to locate, because the history is re-write

If there is a conflict during merging, follow the steps below to resolve

Modify the conflict part
git add
git rebase --continue
(If the third step is invalid, it can be executed git rebase --skip)
Do not habitually execute the git commit command after git add

The Golden Rule of Rebasing rebase

> never use it on public branches

For example, the following scenario: as shown in the figure
[image: donot rebase on public branch]

Now we see what's problem with using rebase on public branches?
If you rebase master to your feature branch:

Rebase moves all master's commits to the top of your feature. The problem is: other people are still developing on the original master. Because you moved the master using rebase, git will think that the history of your master branch is different from that of others and will conflict.

So ask yourself before performing git rebase,

Will anyone else look at this branch?
if YES Do not use this destructive rebase command that modifies the commit history
if NO ok, you can use rebase as you like

## Summary

If you want a clean, linear history tree without merge commit, then you should choose git rebase.
If you want to keep a complete history and want to avoid the risk of rewriting commit history, you should choose to use git merge

### In your described suitation.

- you are advised to use git rebase on yourself own branch. The other guys obey the same rule.
- When someone do squash commit. donot push -f to master branch.
- When handling master branch, use git merge to obtain commit from someone own branch.

Answer (score 0):

1.Dont Give permission to any body  to merge directly into main/master that not a good idea at all make a pr and then you discuss after that you can merge into master/main.

2. it s better resolve that conflicts and if your code is locally You can use rebase No problem to any other developer whose working on that same project or else it can damaged to another developers ,  make sure avoids those things next time.